# How to add a b2Vec2 to a class

Tags: iphone, xcode, box2d, box2d-iphone, cgpoint

I have a class that I want to contain a b2Vec2 and an integer. I keep getting an error that says expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'b2Vec2'. I can't figure this out. Please help.

```
@interface mTouch : NSObject {

  b2Vec2 touchPoint;
  int cannonNumber;
}

-(void)setTouchPoint:(b2Vec2)tp;
-(void)setCannonNumber:(int)cn;
-(b2Vec2)touchPoint;
-(int)cannonNumber;

@end


@implementation mTouch

-(id)init {
  touchPoint = b2Vec2(0, 0);
  cannonNumber = 0;
}

-(void)setTouchPoint:(b2Vec2)tp{
  touchPoint = tp;
}

-(void)setCannonNumber:(int)cn{
  cannonNumber = cn;
}

-(b2Vec2)touchPoint{
  return touchPoint;
}

-(int)cannonNumber{
  return cannonNumber;
}



@end
```

Comment: can you include you error as it displayed on console.

Answer (score 2):

include box2d and make sure the implementation of this header have the extension .mm instead of .m (for supporting c++).